# Inbuilt Ruby function to find CPU Script usage

Tags: ruby

Is there an inbuilt Ruby function which gets the script/processes CPU usage.

This function could be used to terminate a script when it becomes far too CPU heavy, however i am trying to find a function which i built into the ruby language, so that i can avoid using a system command.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Nope. Googling "Ruby get CPU usage" turns up some promising gems, though.

Comment: try running system command through ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a Function/Class builtin in ruby core, but there are some gems that provide this functionality, take a look to one of them:

https://github.com/rderoldan1/usagewatch_ext